# When is the decomposition of a group element as a product of elements of two subgroups unique?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

Let $G$ and $H$ be subgroups of $P$. Assume that every element of $P$ can be expressed as the product of an element of $G$ and an element of $H$.

Under what conditions is this decomposition unique?

This question came up while reading the Wikipedia entry on [direct product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups), but in the wikipedia entry there are two additional assumptions whereas I would rather understand assumption 2. in isolation

> Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, let $P = G \times H$ and consider the following two
>   subsets of $P$:
>
> $$G' = \{ (g,1): g \in G \} \ \text{and}\  H' = \{ (1,h): h \in H \}. $$
>
> [...]
>
> 1. The intersection $G ∩ H$ is trivial.
> 2. Every element of $P$ can be expressed as the product of an element of 
>      $G$ and an element of $H$.
> 3. Every element of $G$ commutes with every element of $H$.

Comment: assumption 1. gives you uniqueness.

Comment: This is the knit product, aka [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa-Szep_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every element of $P$ can be written as a product of an element of $H$ and an element of $G$, then $P=GH$ as sets; but it is a well-known exercise in group theory that given two subgroups $G$ and $H$, the set of products $GH = \{gh\mid g\in G, h\in H\}$ is a (sub)group of $P$ if and only if $GH=HG$ as sets. In particular, if every element of $P$ can be written as a product of an element of $H$ and an element of $G$ in at least one way, then $GH=HG$. Note that this is not the same as your property 3: we just need that for every $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, there exist elements $h’\in H$ and $g’\in G$ such that $gh=h’g’$ and elements $h’’\in H$ and $g’’\in G$ such that $hg=g’’h’’$.

Now, suppose we have uniqueness of the expression. If $x\in G\cap H$, then $x^{-1}\in G\cap H$ (since $G\cap H$ is a subgroup). So $e = ee = xx^{-1}$ gives two ways of expressing $e$ as a product of elements of $G$ and elements of $H$, hence $x=e$. That is, $G\cap H\subseteq \{e\}$. Thus, if you have uniqueness, then the intersection is trivial.

Conversely, suppose the intersection is trivial, and $g,g’\in G$ and $h,h’\in H$ are such that $gh=g’h’$. Then $(g’)^{-1}g = h’h^{-1}\in G\cap H=\{e\}$, hence $(g’)^{-1}g=e$, so $g=g’$; and $h’h^{-1} = e$, so $h’=h$. That is, we get uniqueness of the representation.

In short: you get uniqueness of the representation if and only if the intersection is trivial. But this is weaker than the condition of $G$ being isomorphic to the direct product of $G$ and $H$. We say, in this case, that $G$ and $H$ are **complementary**, or that $G$ is a **complement** of $H$ and vice-versa.